# How to redirect user to login page from middleware in django rest framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-middleware

I'm working with `django rest framework` to build my `api`, and in the front end I'm using `Angular framework`.

I developed a custom `middleware` that intercepts every request. I want to logout the user when the condition is not satisfied.

```
class MyCustomMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            #user is not allowed to do this request 
             #logout the user
```

I know that from the `backend` I can't redirect the user to the login page, it's a `front end` staff, but I want to send a notification or something to the front end to tell it that it should redirect the user to the login page.

I have tried to raise `PermissionError` and `HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN` but none of them worked.

I thought about adding some thing (attribute/parameter) in the header of the request so that in front end interceptor I test if that attribute/parameter exists, but I couldn't find a way for that.

I also tried to set the user of the request to None : `request.user=None` but it also failed.

Could somebody tell me if this is possible or not at first?

If so how can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :D

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseForbidden


class MyCustomMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
   def process_request(self, request):
      if not request.user.is_authenticated():
         #user is not allowed to do this request 
         return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

it was just to raise a `403 error` and from front end side I read the status code of the error, if its  `403` then redirect the user to the login page.

I Hope it helps somebody in the future.